# Find $\sinh^{-1}x$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

The hyperbolic sine function, $\sinh(x)$ ,  is defined by the equation:

$$ \sinh(x) = \frac {e^x-e^{-x}} {2}$$
Find a formula for its inverse, $$ \sinh^{-1}(x) $$

Comment: Please include your thoughts and efforts (work in progress) in this and future posts. 
You are more likely to receive positive/constructive feedback that way.  
Formatting your post helps too.
Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y=\sinh^{-1}(x)$.
$$
x={e^y-e^{-y}\over2}\implies e^{2y}-2xe^{y}-1=0\implies e^{y}=x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\\
\implies\sinh^{-1}(x)=\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})
$$

Comment: Could you please explain how you got from step 2: when it was = to 0 , to step 3: with the squareroot.

Comment: Solve a quadratic equation in $e^y$ and remember $e^y>0$.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification, and thanks for the help overall :)